# How to trigger elixir supervisor tree termination from a supervised worker process

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I am trying to terminate whole supervision tree from a supervised worker process. Here is my supervision tree:

```
                   +--------------------------+
                   |                          |
          +--------+ Sup1: Dynamic Supervisor +---------+
          |        |                          |         |
          |        +-------------+------------+         |
          |                      |                      |
          |                      |                      |
          v                      v                      v

+------------------+   +------------------+  +------------------+
|                  |   |                  |  |                  |
| Job1: Supervisor |   | Job2: Supervisor |  | Job3: Supervisor |
|                  |   |                  |  |                  |
+------------------+   +-+-------- +---+--+  +------------------+
                         |             |
                         |             |
                         |             |
                         |             |
                         v             v

             +-------------------+  +--------------+
             |                   |  |              |
             | Progress Monitor: |  | Work: Worker |
             |       Worker      |  |              |
             |                   |  +--------------+
             +-------------------+
```

**Process life cycle:**

1. A `Job` is started via: `DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, spec)`
2. Each job is a supervision tree as well: 1 supervisor (restart strategy - `one_for_one`) -> 2 workers
3. `Progress Monitor` worker knows when the given job is done
4. On job done, `Progress Monitor` worker makes an attempt to terminate the whole job supervision tree, by calling: `DynamicSupervisor.terminate_child(__MODULE__, pid)`
5. `Progress Monitor` is expected to do cleanup steps in `terminate` callback - it is trapping exit signals

**Problems and observations:**

1. `DynamicSupervisor.terminate_child` is a blocking call, which means it waits for all child processes to terminate as well, including the calling process - `Progress Monitor`
2. `Progress Monitor` is in a deadlock and can not terminate. Parent supervisor sends `:kill` signal, which does not trigger `terminate` callback

**Quick workarounds:**

1. Call `DynamicSupervisor.terminate_child` from `Progress Monitor` worker asynchronously:

   `spawn(fn ->  DynamicSupervisor.terminate_child(__MODULE__, pid) end)`
2. Define shutdown strategy for `Sup1: Dynamic Supervisor`:

   `shutdown: 5_000`

   It will wait at most 5s for a job supervision tree termination and then it will send `shutdown` exit signal. This will ensure `terminate` callback being called for `Progress Monitor` process.

Not happy with both of them.

**Questions:**

1. How to trigger supervision tree termination from a worker process and avoid deadlocks?
2. If terminating supervision tree from a worker is not the best practice, what is the recommended way then?
3. Any recommendations how to redesign supervision tree to make graceful termination easier?

Comment: It seems to me that the `Progress Monitor` is unnecessary. Could you explain the reason why the `Worker` cannot simply do its thing and then terminate with reason `normal`? It seems like you could be using `Task.Supervisor` for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Just call it in async task `Task.async(fn -> Process.exit(Sup1, :shutdown) end)` it will terminate Sup1 and with it all children will shutdown

EDIT:

If you need prettier solution, it depends what elese you need. In most cases, I create Bootstrapper worker that will do initialization and some other stuff. You could add easily other features.

So considering above, and just roughly speaking, I would add in a layer above (`AppSupervisor`), Another DynamicSupervisor so it can start Bootstrapper and pass `self()` to it (or register it under local name to avoid this injection). After that, on start, Bootstrap worker will start Sup1 (your dynamic supervisor) and await for other messages, e.g. `:terminate_sup1` that will shutdown `Sup1` process. Later, in some of below workers you can shutdown `Sup1` by casting `:terminate_sup1` message to bootstraper. Also there is  a door that allow you to start again Sup1 when another message is sent to bootstrap worker.

Further more, if you just need to shutdown Sup1, just go with Task. But if you need control, then put it into single worker process that should have control over it, when it is up or down.